# Angular.js animations

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, angularjs-directive

I have a block with `ng-repeat` that is defined like this:

```
<div ng-show="isPageSelected(item.page)" class="block" ng-repeat="item in data">
  ...
</div>
```

Currently I can switch between those blocks, by clicking certain elements. It works via `ng-show="isPageSelected(item.page)"` as you might have guessed. It all works fine, but they are switching instantly and I want to add an animation, a simple fade in/fade out will do.

So, the block that is no longer selected should fade out and when it's gone a new block should fade in. When I'm using `ngAnimate` they fade in and fade out simultaneously. I need the first block to disappear completely and be hidden with `display: none;` and when it's done the next block should appear and fade in. It's a rather straightforward task when using jQuery, but how do I do that elegantly with Angular.js?

I have a strong suspicion that Angular.js isn't exactly a good choice for a site with complex animations.

EDIT: To simplify my question, all I need to do is

1. On a button click start an animation;
2. When an animation has been finished, change model;
3. Run another animation.

Since I need to change the model after an animation, it's probably not possible to do it via pure CSS. The only way I know of triggering animations on specific elements in angular is to create a directive, pass a scope variable into the directive, create watcher for that variable in the directive and then change the variable from the controller:

```
<div animation="page"></div>
```

---

```
app.directive('animation', function(){
    return {
        scope: { page: '=animation' },
        link: function(scope, element){
            scope.$watch('page', function(newVal){
                ...
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I guess it would work, but it seems really bloated to create a directive just for that. Also, how would I change `$scope.page` with this approach only when the animation has been finished? Add another scope variable just to trigger an animation and somehow change `$scope.page` when an animation has been finished? It's possible to do it with `ngFx` module, but the amount of code it takes is just ridiculous. At this point I think adding jQuery animations to the controller would be a prettier way to solve it.

EDIT: That's how it looks like with jQuery animations:

```
$scope.changePage = function(page) {
  $('.block').animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function(){
    $scope.page.id = page;
    $scope.$apply();
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
  });
};
```

It works fine and it's not quite as verbose as the way with directives, but I have to use CSS selectors and that's just feels very "unangular". Do you guys use something similar when dealing with animations?

EDIT: Somewhat similar approach using `ngFx`:

```
    <div ng-hide="switchPageAnimation" 
             class="block fx-fade-normal fx-speed-300 fx-trigger">
```

---

In the controller:

```
  $scope.switchPageAnimation = false;

  $scope.changePage = function(page) {
    if($scope.page.id === page || $scope.switchPageAnimation) return;
    $scope.switchPageAnimation = true;
    $scope.$on('fade-normal:enter', function(){
      $scope.page.id = page;
      $scope.switchPageAnimation = false;
    });
  };
```

I'm not using CSS selectors, but still it looks awful. I have to define a scope variable for the animation and then check if the animation is already running. I feel like I am missing something really obvious.

Comment: what version of angular and angular-animate are you using?

Comment: The latest ones bower installs, but I can install any other version if that's important

Comment: Angular's version is `1.3.8`. I'm also using `ngFx` with version `1.0.5`. Angular-animate has the same version as Angular, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: with angular 1.3 u have the $animate service https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate  there u can register promise callbacks when the animation is complete

Comment: Okay, but how do I trigger it initially? If I put it inside a directive, I'll have to create a scope variable to trigger it, right? That's the whole problem. If I'm going to use CSS selectors, then I can just stick with jQuery. Please, provide an example, if I'm misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this will help you and it is not necessary in your case to wait for the animation to finish. If your pages have css position: absolute and are in a container with position: relative then they share the same place and are not shown one below the other while animation. With this setting you can crossfade or delay the show animation

transition-delay:

```
.container1{
    position: relative;
    height:400px;
}

.block1{
    position:absolute;
}
.block1.ng-hide-add-active {
    display: block!important;
    -webkit-transition: 2s linear all;
    transition: 2s linear all;
}
.block1.ng-hide-remove-active {
    display: block!important;
    -webkit-transition: 2s linear all;
    transition: 2s linear all;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
.block1.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ncrs4gz0/

**Edit:**
If u use a filter in ng-repeat instead of ng-show to show a selected page like this

```
<div  class="block1" ng-repeat="item in data | filter:isPageSelected">
```

then the pages are added and removed from the dom and angular add classes ng-enter , ng-enter-active and ng-leave ng-leave-active

but the animation can be defined similar see fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/o944epzy/

Comment: Okay, that's nice, but it won't work if the pages were switched by using something like that: `<div ng-repeat="video in videos | onlyPage:page" class="col-item">`, i.e. they would be removed from the dom when `page` is changed. I'm using this approach in another place and still forced to use jQuery for it

Comment: than u have to use .col-item.ng-enter-active and .col-item.ng-leave-active  -there are a lot of examples on google animating for ng-repeat

Comment: Thank you, you are being very helpful! I assume there is no way to make it work if there is more than a single element in ng-repeat though, right? I mean, if we use `position: absolute` we can't put a few elements next to each other without specifying their exact position. Oh, well.

Comment: we only use this setting with position absolute in a relative container when we have page like transitions. when more than a single element is shown in ng-repeat than the elements have position: relative or even floating.Here a few examples http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/appear  http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-12/app/#/phones http://www.htmlxprs.com/post/9/easy-angularjs-animations-using-animatecss

Answer (score 2):

Effectively you have to use CSS for showing and hiding elements from your ng-repeat;
when you use ngAnimate, do not forget to inject it in your module.

```
.module('myModule', [  'ngAnimate', ...
```

Doing that when you will add/remove an element from you ng-repeat source of data.
Angular will add and remove the class `ng-enter, ng-leave`. 
[Here](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html) is a good tutorial about animation with ngAnimate.

In your own case you want to change page. I suggest you have too many items for displaying all at once.

You can declare in your scope two variable :

```
$scope.elemByPage = 5;
$scope.page = 0;
$scope.nbPages = ...; // I let you do the maths ;)
```

and after in your template you can do simply this:

```
<div class="my-repeat-item" data-ng-repeat="item in data | pager:page:elemByPage">
 {{item.xxx}}           
</div>
```

This template will only show the needed items in function of the page number and number of elements per page. 
Pager is a simple filter and it does the trick

```
.filter('pager',[function(){
        return function(items, page, nbElemByPage) {

            if(!nbElemByPage || nbElemByPage < 1) {
                return items;
            }

            var nbPages = Math.floor(items.length/nbElemByPage);
            if(nbPages<1) {
                return items;
            }

            var startIndex = page*nbElemByPage;

            return items.splice(startIndex, nbElemByPage);
        };
    }])
```

Now you just have to use button that will allow you to browser your items

```
<button data-ng-click="page = page - 1"/>Prev page</button>
<button data-ng-click="page = page - 1"/>Next page</button>
```

To finish you want to add a fade in animation on new items so declare in your css these classes following the class of your items (here `my-repeat-item`)

```
.my-repeat-item.ng-enter {
    transition: 0.6s ease all;
    opacity:0;
}
.my-repeat-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity:1;
}
```

You can do the same thing when a item is removed by replacing `enter` with `leave`.

Hope it will answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively you have to use CSS for showing and hiding elements from your ng-repeat; when you use ngAnimate, do not forget to inject it in your module.

Answer (score -1):

You can add your desired transition to the CSS class of the element to show/hide:

```
animate-show.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
```

See more here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#example

In fact, using CSS is the 'right' way to do it even though it even though it might feel un-angular.